# Getting Layer DataSource information in ArcObjects with C#?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#

I have a mxd file with 6 layers. I want to get datasource information for each layer. Please see the code below. I want to know how exactly i should get layer's datasource information

```
IDocument doc = ArcMap.Application.Document;
IMxDocument mxDoc = doc as IMxDocument;

IMap map = mxDoc.FocusMap;

ILayer layer = map.get_Layer(0);// Layer[0];
```

Comment: Are you OK with an [arcpy solution](https://community.esri.com/thread/30118)? It could be run interactively in the Python window in ArcGIS or via Python directly.

Comment: @smiller, I am creating an Add-In button and on click on this button i will grab datacource information. Since all of my code is currently in C# it would be great to have a C# solution.

Comment: Which information do you want to get?

Comment: @Kadir, I want Server, Connection Properties, Database, User name and although Password is not getting displayed in Layer Properties window but i would like to get password too only if its possible.

Comment: @smiller : I found the solution. Look at my answer

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer for my question. Please look at below mentioned code,

```
IDocument doc = ArcMap.Application.Document;
IMxDocument mxDoc = doc as IMxDocument;
IMap map = mxDoc.FocusMap;
ILayer layer = map.get_Layer(0);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer featureLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer)layer;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass featureClass = featureLayer.FeatureClass;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDataset dataSet = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDataset)featureClass;      
ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IPropertySet propertySet = dataSet.Workspace.ConnectionProperties;
object propertyNames;
object propertyValues;
propertySet.GetAllProperties(out propertyNames, out propertyValues);
System.Array propNameArray = (System.Array)propertyNames;
System.Array propValuesArray = (System.Array)propertyValues;
```